# How can I port a Flash application to the BlackBerry PlayBook

Tags: actionscript, blackberry, flash-builder, blackberry-playbook

I have a Flash application written in ActionScript 2 that I would like to port to the BlackBerry Playbook. The application is composed of an .swf file and a directory containing a large number of vector images. The path to these images (e.g. imagefolder/icons/icon1.swf) is hard-coded into an application and requires the image directory and the .swf file to be in the same directory.

I've installed the PlayBook SDK and have tried packaging the application with FlashBuilder 4, but I have no experience with this programme and have so far been unsuccessful. I tried placing the application in an SWFLoader component, but I then realised after reading [this pdf document](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/21829/BlackBerry_Tablet_OS_SDK-Feature_and_Technical_Overview--1356116-1021110927-001-1.0-US.pdf) that MXML components are not supported. Since the app is written in AS2, I believe it cannot be compiled by Flash Builder. I don't need any any of the AIR features so I was wondering how could I embed the .swf and image directory in a Flash Builder ActionScript project so that it would run on the BlackBerry PlayBook.

Answer (score 0):

The playbook uses AIR to play, so you need to be able to run it in AIR, which means that you need to have it working in as3. You could try "tricking it" by loading the AVM1 into AVM2.